# How to approve Paypal adaptive preapproval payment from code to be used in tests

Tags: .net, testing, paypal, integration-testing, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am looking into cover our PayPal integration with integration tests to verify all payment flows work correct.

We are currently supporting both Stripe and Paypal as payment providers.
With Stripe, its possible to generate payment tokens etc. through their api and thereby "simulate" an end to end payment scenario.

I am looking into doing the same with Paypal adaptive payments (preapproval flow), but I can't seem to find any resources for "approving" my preapproval token through their API.

Even if I assign a sender to the preapproval request where I have permissions to make charges on their behalf (3rd party "AUTH_CAPTURE").

Anyone that can help point me in the right direction for fully automated testing of paypal payment flows.
Having to manually log in and approve every key for every test is not a scalable solution :(

I already have working implementation of the needed functionality, but I would like to completely automate the testing of the integration.

What I am trying to achieve in my testcase:

```
[Test]
public void _Test(){
    s.AuthorizePayment(booking);
    s.ApprovePaymentTokenInTest(booking.PaymentToken); <----
    s.CapturePayment(booking).Should().BeTrue();
}

public void AuthorizePayment(Booking booking){
    ...
    preapproveRequest.senderEmail = TestSenderEmail;

    AdaptivePaymentsService adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService(configurationMap);
    PreapprovalResponse preapprovalResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Preapproval(preapproveRequest);
    ...
}


public bool CapturePayment(Booking booking){
    ...
    pr.preapprovalKey = booking.PaymentToken;
    PayResponse payResponse = adaptivePaymentsService.Pay(pr);
    ...     

    return payResponse.paymentExecStatus == PayPalPaymentState.Completed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look on the official page of Preapproval API Operation for PayPal. It is a sample code for sandbox environment as well.
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/

Comment: Hey Gabriel.
I've updated my question with some code to give some clearity to my question.

Your answer:
I'm not really able to find anything on the page you are refering to, that would help me approving the preapproval key from an API perspective. But I might completely be missing something.